# How to add an Alert after page-loading with an php-value

Tags: javascript, php, database, pdf, blob

I have a web-application where I can upload pdf-files into the database. My signing-programm allows only pdf-files with pdf-verion 1.4, so I want check the version directly by upload the file. So when I upload the file, I start this one to get the content of the file in JS:

```
document.getElementById("selectedFile_upload").addEventListener('change', check_pdfVersion, false);

function check_pdfVersion(evt) {
    alert("check_pdfVersion...");
    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    var blob = new Blob([file], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('pdf_chkv', blob);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("PDF Version wird geprüft");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("FKT.check_pdfVersion erreicht aber etwas ist schief gelaufen")
        }
    })
}

function pdfVersion_result(evt) {
    alert("pdf version: " + evt.target.files[0].str);
}
```

I send here my pdf-data to PHP for check the version. I think it will give a possibility to check the version in JS and I try this way but it not works:

```
    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
            jQuery('#selectedFile_upload').val(e.target.result);
        };
    })(file);

    reader.readAsText("file: " + file);

    alert(reader);
```

My PHP-file:

```
if(isset($_FILES['pdf_chkv'])) {
    if(!$_FILES['pdf_chkv']['error']) {
        handle_pdfCheck();
    }
}

function handle_pdfCheck() {
    $pdfFile_raw = file_get_contents($_FILES['pdf_chkv']['tmp_name']);

    $result = pdfVersion($pdfFile_raw);

    ?>

    <script>
        var result = '<?php echo $result; ?>';

        alert("PDF Version: ");
        alert(result);
    </script>

    <?php

    if(strcmp($result,'1.4') != 0) {
        die("Ihre PDF-Version ist " . $result . ". Dieses System kann derzeit nur PDF-Version 1.4 verarbeiten.");
    }
}
```

I get the version of the file in the php variable $result but I dont get the alert in the js-code with this result. I think its because the document is allready loaded. How I can show the user the pdf-version of his uploaded file directly after selecting the file in html?

greets and sorry for my english,
ilikefatcats

Answer (score 0):

To  alert the *PDF version* of the uploaded file you can directly echo the `$result` into the `alert()` as

```
alert("PDF Version: <?php echo $result; ?>");
```

[image]

Comment: unfornatelly its not working. I dont get the alert at all, so the behavior is the same like in my way. I think its because the document is allready loaded when the function handle_pdfCheck() will called.

Comment: I have posted an working example here ill show you.

Comment: Yes - so it wokrs. My problem is, that in my case the page is already loaded. When a user selects a file for upload (<input type="file" name="upl_file" class="custom-file-input" id="selectedFile_upload" aria-describedby="upload-prepend" lang="de">) It will start my javascript code which is calling the php-function handle_pdfCheck() with an ajax-POST-request and here, in the php-code, I want to display the version-number in the alert but no alert opens. I could write alert("hello world"); but its not working... I think I have to append the alert afterwards to the page or something like that

Comment: So you can use `onclick()` function  for that for eg : `onclick()` of `input[type = file]` run call the   `handle_pdfCheck()` function and it will work perfectly fine.